# install geotrust quickssl on apache2 ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, apache2

I usually outsource installing a ssl cert. However I want to learn this process.
So I ssh'ed into my server and ran the below code

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mydomain.com.key -out mydomain.com.csr
```

I then answered all the needed questions and this generated the key and CSR file. I then ran this command in order to copy the contents of the csr

```
cat example.com.csr
```

I then pasted it into the ssl reseller order form where it asked me to paste the csr content.

I then verify my domain name and get a zip file. Now here is where I was looking for guidance as I am not able to find a tutorial that matches the files I received. FYI I choose SHA-2 when pasting the csr into the certificate reseller

So I received a zip file containing 4 files a named CACertificate-1 then one named CACertificate-2 both which are .cer files not .crt file extensions and a file named ServerCertificate as well as a 4th file named IconScript which seems to be a html/javascript file that calls out to an external javascript.

Now my question is 
I see a few tutorials that say in my apache2 virtualhost file I would add the below

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/myexample.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/myexample.com.key
```

However I do not have a .crt file I have 3 .cer files?? Do I reference all three in my virtual host file and if so how? No I merge them all into one file that I then rename with a .crt extention instead of a .cer extention?

Lastly the .key file I reference in the virtual host that would be the key file that I created when I created the csr correct?

thanks all for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript you don't need (and probably don't want) but you do want both your signed certificate as well as any intermediate certificates provided by the CA.

TLS clients are only expected to know about the root certificate, but the CA typically has at least one intermediate certificate in the chain between their root and your certificate, so you want to make sure that your server provides the whole rest of the chain, not just your own certificate.

You can combine these certificates (.crt or .cer are used interchangeably, what matters is that the certificates are in PEM format) into a single file, this is done by simply concatenating the files (ordered from leaf to root). See [the documentation for SSLCertificateFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) for details.

As a sidenote, you may also want to have a look at [Mozilla's Server Side TLS recommendations](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) (including their config generator) for a sane set of TLS settings.

Comment: So then I would merge the certificate that geotrust provided and then the intermediate certificate but what is the root certificat